# FilterExpression to get Count in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How to get a particular count of rows back from Dynamodb. I've done a scan and set a limit (say 15). How, do I pick just the first 5 of the 15 results? I know I need to use a FilterExpression, but I'm unsure how and where to set the Count.

I've looked at the [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) documentation, but I'm not sure how to use this in a nodejs application.

Comment: What exactly do you want? When you set a limit of 15, then only 15 results will be scanned. If there is no `filterExpression` then 15 results will be returned otherwise filtered results from those 15 will be returned.

Comment: @Prakashsharma I want to be able to retrieve a subset of the scanned results. If I scan 15, I want to be able to retrieve only 5 even though 15 are scanned.

Comment: Then just put limit of 5. It will return only five results. Why do you want to scan 15 but use/return only 5?

Comment: @Prakashsharma I simplified the scenario just to make the question clear. I need to be able to get a subset of the results.